# How do I read from a Json fromat?

Tags: php, python, json

I am using this code bit:

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
    from datetime import datetime
    import json
    import cx_Oracle
    import requests
    /*Some other code bits*/

    longitude = 0.0
    latitude = 0.0
            try:
                params = {
                        'action': 'query',
                        'country': 'Hungary',
                        'city': 'Budapest',
                        'format' : 'json',
                        }
                res = requests.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php', params=params)
                page = res.json()
                latitude = page['lat']
                longitude =page['lon']
            except:
                pass 
            return jsonify(name=result[0],address=result[1],phone=result[2],income=result[3],Latitude = latitude, Longitude=longitude)
```

And I am trying to get the latitude and logitude from this link that is in JSON format: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?action=query&format=json&city=Budapest&country=Hungary

name=result[0],address=result[1],phone=result[2],income=result[3] are fine, and work well, however, I must be doing something wrong becouse Latitude and Longitude remains 0.0.
If I remove the intialization from line 1, and 2, then I get and error that

```
       UnboundLocalError: local variable 'latitude' referenced before assignment
```

probably becouse it runs into some kind of error within the try block.

I am sorry for this easy question I am very new to python and JSON.

Comment: there's an exception and latitude hasn't been set yet. you should also explicitly set the type of Exception you want to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is contained within a list, which very confusing to beginners. If you see []'s in the response, you have to use a numerical index to reference the content inside of those brackets. Then you can reference by keyword for the dict inside.  Use requests to fetch JSON.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?action=query&format=json&city=Budapest&country=Hungary').json()

print(r[0]['lon'])

print(r[0]['lat'])
```

Output:
19.0404707
47.4983815

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Thank you, it worked, it missed the [0] index before ['lat'] and ['lon']!